# Как расположить блок по центру?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!) Как при таком раскладе расположить блок forest по центру?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="fon1"><img src="fon1.png"/></div>
<div class="fon2"><img src="fon2.png"/></div>
    <div class="forest">
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

div.fon1
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
div.fon2
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
div.forest
{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #000;
  background-image: url("1.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 2%;
 }
div.main
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #000;
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Как-то так?](http://jsfiddle.net/5grVA/1/)

```
<div class="fon1"><img src="fon1.png"/></div>
<div class="fon2"><img src="fon2.png"/></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="forest">
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

и

```
div.fon1
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
div.fon2
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
div.forest
{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #000;
  background-image: url("1.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
div.main
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #000;
}

.wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Если что - то я добавил блок wrapper, в который поместил forest, а также указал для wrapper ширину, равную ширине forest (точнее, main) и margin: 0 auto;